# Event not showing in FullCalendar which starts from 11:30 PM and ends at 12 AM and later using Angular 12 and later

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am currently working on an Angular 12 project and utilizing FullCalendar to display events. I encountered an issue where events starting from 11:30 PM and ending at 12 AM (midnight) or later are not displaying on the calendar.
I have tried adding the events to the calendar using the following code:

```
// Angular component code
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];
  events = [
    {
      title: 'Late Event',
      start: '2023-07-24T23:30:00',
      end: '2023-07-25T00:30:00' // Event should end at 12:30 AM
    },
    // Other events...
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Fetch events from server or perform other initialization tasks.
  }
}
```

The issue is that the "Late Event" starting at 11:30 PM and ending at 12:30 AM is not visible on the calendar. Events starting and ending at other times display correctly.

I have checked my code for any potential errors, but I cannot find anything that could be causing this issue. I suspect it might be related to the way FullCalendar handles events spanning across midnight.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with FullCalendar in an Angular 12 project? Is there a specific configuration or option that needs to be set to display events that start from late evening and end at midnight or later?

Any help or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyQqmNq . That is using vanilla JS, but the way fullCalendar processes and displays event data internally isn't any different, whether you are using pure JS, or Angular, or any other plugin.